# Creating layout for all the screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, screen-resolution, screen-size

I have an application that is close to finish. Now, what I don't know is how to design layouts for all the phones and tablets, should I do it with layout-small and that stuff or `layout-sw320` and similar?

How many layouts should there be and how to create layout for all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is relevant documentation you should read to gain necessary knowledge: [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)